# Laravel Dusk logs in as wrong user

Tags: laravel-5.5, laravel-dusk

I have a fairly simple browser test (laravel dusk). The test fails, not because of the actual asserts but because of missing permissions.

The user with which I login (`loginAs`) has those permissions. It turned out that in the end, although I log in as *testUser* the actual authenticated user is another user.

It seems that the authenticated user switches between the `loginAs()` and accessing the controller function. But as I see it, these two steps should come one after another.

I gave my best to explain the situation if something is unclear please ask for clarification.

**Test**

```
/**
* @throws \Throwable
*/
public function test_something()
{
   $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
   $browser->loginAs($this->testUser) //made a breakpoint here and it showed the correct user
      ->visit(new IndexPage())
      //some asserts
   });
}
```

**Corresponding Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    dd(Auth::user()->username); //shows not the name of testUser
    if (! Auth::user()->can('index'))
        return abort(403, "Operation not permitted"); //fails because of wrong user

    //gather data

    return view('index', compact('data'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually I would simply delete this question as it turned out as some kind of beginner's mistake. But as someone "starred" this question I'd rather answer it.
I can't tell exactly where the issue came from but I cleared everything I could clear (caches) and now the test goes green.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue has something to do with the way Dusk logs itself in. I noticed that my observers would always get null when trying to access the current user despite having called `$browser->loginAs($user)`. My solution was to also call `\Auth::login($user)` which solves the problem.

It's important to remember that the PHP process running dusk tests is completely isolated from the application code which can lead to a lot of confusion.

Long term solution is probably to abandon Dusk and use WebDriver directly as the zero-config nature of Dusk leaves developers very confused when something going wrong and that's particularly bad with something as flaky as Laravel Dusk.